# Pyramid: How to I avoid putting full paths into my __init__.py

Tags: python, path, pyramid

I need to pull a configuration file in my main function:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """ 

    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    ret = parser.read('/var/www/finance/corefinance/database.ini')
    connstring = parser.get('postgres', 'connstring')
    settings['sqlalchemy.url'] = connstring
```

The location of database.ini is one level up from the location of the **init**.py

I thought I could just use "../database.ini", but that doesn't work. The only thing that works is putting in the whole path. How can I avoid putting in a full path in this file?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, within your **__init__.py** you can just define a variable using a string representation of your project's parent directory:

```
project_dir = '/var/www/finance/corefinance/'
```

But I'm sure you're not asking on SO to get an answer like that.

---

Another way is to add something similar to the following line within the `[app:main]` portion of your **development.ini** and **production.ini**:

```
project_dir = %(here)s/mycoolwebsite
```

Or maybe even just:

```
project_dir = %(here)s
```

Then in your **__init__.py** (and anywhere else you want to reference the project's parent directory) you can retrieve that value with:

```
project_dir = config.registry.settings['project_dir']
```

For more information on custom variables, see: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting

Comment: This is a good answer, but my difficulty is I'm trying to keep from hard coding absolute paths in the .ini files  because then source control will try to store the changes when I'm creating development environments.  I created database.ini in the first place to keep all this info out of source control, but now I've got this chicken and egg problem.

Comment: It's not an absolute path, in the sense that it's relative to %(here)s. Ordinarily, the stuff in the project_dir is just transferred as is for production. What changes were you planning on making between the directory structure of development vs production?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass it as an argument, you can use argv of course and also resolve the path using os.path

```
import os
import sys
...
path = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
ret = parser.read(path)
...
```

Comment: That might work, but I was really hoping for something more along the lines of accessing a current pyramid settings variable or being able to pass in a path as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work based on @tag's idea:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """ 

    parser = SafeConfigParser()
    iniloc = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'database.ini'))
    read_list = parser.read(iniloc)
    connstring = parser.get('postgres', 'connstring')
    settings['sqlalchemy.url'] = connstring
```